# Understanding the logic of WaitGroups

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'd like to understand if my logic around WaitGroups is correct and to see if there is a more efficient way of structuring my code. The aim is to perform the tasks as fast as possible.

My code populates a `_urls` channel which is populated via stdin. Then I'm spinning up two WaitGroups, one which reads from this `_urls` channel, and the other which reads from a `_downloads` channel, which is fed from a goroutine in the first WaitGroup.

Essentially the code looks like this:

```
    // declare channels
    _urls := make(chan string)
    _downloads := make(chan string)

    // first waitgroup with 2 goroutines
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {

        wg.Add(2)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for url := range _urls {
                // perform GET request and inspect the responseBody    
            }

        }()

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for url := range _urls {
                // perform a HEAD request to look for a certain file
                // if the file exists, send to the _downloads channel                
                _downloads <- url
            }
        }()
    }

    // second waitgroup with 1 goroutine
    var dwg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {

        dwg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for url := range _downloads {
                // perform the download
            }
        }()
    }
```

My concern is around whether this is an efficient way to feed the `_downloads` channel, or would it make more sense to just perform the download within the first WaitGroup.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to use wait groups at all in your example. What was the reason you added them? You're also never waiting for them to finish, so they're no-ops in your example.

Comment: @Flimzy tbh I saw a similar structure of code in some blogs and other github repos, therefore assumed it must be right...

Comment: It probably was right, for the problem they were solving. That doesn't mean it's right for the problem you are solving.

Comment: I started writing a detailed answer, but there's not enough info in your code to propose the right structure. It's not at all clear how your first two goroutines (which do a GET and HEAD respectively) relate to each other, or to the final goroutine (which does the download).  But I see no reason to use waitgroups at all here.

Comment: @Flimzy ok I appreciate your comment, it's made me re-think the logic. The first goroutine is looking for the presence of a particular string in the responseBody, the second performs a HEAD to look for the presence of a particular file within the URL path, therefore they are separate routines. If the HEAD request finds the file, I felt it more efficient to pass to another channel which would concurrently perform the download without blocking the next HEAD.

Comment: Does the HEAD need to wait for the GET, or they can happen simultaneously?

Comment: @Flimzy - nope completely separate. Can happen simultaneously.

Comment: Okay. Then you'll need two channels. As written, each URL will go _either_ to the GET goroutine or the HEAD goroutine, not both.  And then each of those goroutines should just exit when their respective channels are closed (no need for a waitgroup)

Comment: Then your HEAD goroutine will feed the channel for the final goroutine, which in turn can exit when that channel is closed. Again, no need for a waitgroup.

Comment: @Flimzy - ok that makes sense, I had no idea each URL would go to _either_ goroutine, that's definitely not what I intended. I feel I can refactor what I need now based on your comments, therefore I appreciate it.

Comment: sync.WaitGroups lets you wait until a certain number of independent things signal they are done. That is all to know about WaitGroups. Its about waiting until a group of things are done. Whether this is the "best" or "fastest" or "most idiomatic" depends so much on the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this with the worker pool pattern, https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools.  Probably the right direction if you are looking to maximizing concurrency.

It abstracts jobs using go interfaces, so it could be a HEAD, GET, Download, or whatever else happens to make sense in the future.  A scheduler sends jobs to a dispatcher that manages the worker pool and sends results back.

Here is a link to the [README](https://github.com/pavedroad-io/templates/blob/master/sampleServices/eventcollector/README.md) and code.

It uses wait groups to track the number of active workers, not jobs. Workers execute a `for {} loop` and only exit when they read true from a done channel.  In this case, the use of the wait group is for a graceful shutdown.  In your example, many of the workers could be doing long downloads.  So your shutdown logic could wait for N jobs to be left before shutting down.

It may be overkill for your use cases.

Comment: No problem.  FYI, depending on your workload, using Go channels may be too limiting as it requires all workers to be in a single process space on a single compute node.  I am planning on a second version that uses Kafka as a message bus.  That will allow for multiple processes and compute nodes.